# Getter for Angular service property instead of storing it in component

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, service

I have a component, `MainComponent`, which needs access to a `User` object stored in `MainService`.

Instead of storing the `User` object both in `MainComponent` and `MainService`, would it be considered bad practice to set up a getter in `MainComponent`, which returns the instance from `MainService`? This way, the `User` object would only be stored in one place.

```
export class MainComponent implements OnInit {
   get user() {
      return this.mainService.user;
   }
```

```
@Injectable()
export class MainService {
    User!: IUser;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having dug into the Angular DI docs (https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-in-action), I discovered that this is actually the exact approach they used for the HeroCacheService:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-hero-bio',
  template: `
    <h4>{{hero.name}}</h4>
    <ng-content></ng-content>
    <textarea cols="25" [(ngModel)]="hero.description"></textarea>`,
  providers: [HeroCacheService]
})

export class HeroBioComponent implements OnInit  {
  @Input() heroId = 0;

  constructor(private heroCache: HeroCacheService) { }

  ngOnInit() { this.heroCache.fetchCachedHero(this.heroId); }

  // This part here answered my question!
  get hero() { return this.heroCache.hero; }
}
```